# How Secure is MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Due to MonoTouch using dll's within the actual app, how secure is this approach?  For instance, if someone is using the Mono.Security.dll, couldn't someone swap out that dll with one which implemented the methods and perform a code injection attack on an app?

Comment: Are signed assemblies supposed to help with that?

Comment: If you have a valid developer or enterprise licence, you can take any IPA and re-sign the whole thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> how secure is this approach?

As much as any existing ones I know :-)

> couldn't someone swap out that dll

No for several reasons.

- You cannot change the applications files. That would break the digital signature and iOS won't execute it. That alone removes a MitM attack;
- the code from **every** .dll is already compiled to native code (by the AOT compiler) and part of the main executable binary. Swapping a new .dll won't change the code that is executed;
- the .dll that is deployed on devices is *stripped* (for release builds). There's no IL (code) inside it since it would not be useful (we can't JIT on iOS). Even if you add a .dll with IL code (e.g. a debug build) it won't be executed (again it would require JITting);

**Why are the .dll deployed ?** for their metadata (e.g. if you use reflection)

**Final note:** MonoTouch produce native ARM executables just like Objective-C would.

Comment: Point 1 isn't valid though as I said, you can resign the whole IPA if you have a valid developer or enterprise certificate, and you can then run that on a device.  Thanks for the information on not being able to swap out the dll's though :-)

Comment: If you can convince people to install anything you did/sign then a MitM attack is not your worse concern ;-) It's also a general iOS problem, nothing specific to MonoTouch

Comment: That's if you are looking at it from something like a malware angle.  If you're looking at it as a way to compromise an enterprises security, you wouldn't be doing it to distribute

Comment: I think @poupou's point is that it is just as secure as an Obj-c app (and just as vulnerable).